# mysql display row values as column in joining

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables

```
classes
id class
1  10th
2  9th
3  8th
....

students
id name    class_id...
1  smith   2
2  gyle    3
......

attendances
id  date        student_id  attendance
1   2014-01-01       1       P
2   2014-01-01       2       A
3   2014-01-02       1       P
4   2014-01-02       2       P
.....
```

I want to display total number of present student in each class on each (group by) date as following

```
date         10th   9th   8th  .....
2014-01-01    12     11   13   .....
2014-01-02    13     11   12   .....
2014-01-01    13     10   13   .....
....................................
```

Comment: ...and what did you try?

Comment: That's a pivot query and mysql doesn't support them. The workarounds get ugly VERY fast. Do a regular joined query and then do the row->column transformation in your code. It's trivially simple code, and you'll spend less time working on that than you would getting the pivot to work in the query.

Comment: I tried simple joining which display in rows, while I do not have any idea how can this be accomplished